# How to stop a thread from running indefinitely in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios-multithreading

I run a function from a library which I can't see the implementation.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    someClass.beginService();
});
```

This library class calls my class' delegate function.

```
class Mine: UIViewController, SomeClassDelegate {

    let someClass = SomeClass();

    override func viewDidLoad () {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        someClass.delegate = self;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            self.someClass.beginService();
        });
    }

    func delegateCall () {
        print ("delegateCall is called!");
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

The word `delegateCall is called!` is then printed periodically every 1 second in the log window, because I call the `self.someClass.beginService();`.

The problem is, how can I terminate this thread? I don't want to resort to:

```
class Mine: UIViewController, SomeClassDelegate {

    let someClass = SomeClass();
    var okToRun = false;

    override func viewDidLoad () {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        someClass.delegate = self;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            self.someClass.beginService();
            okToRun = true;
        });
    }

    func delegateCall () {
        if okToRun {
            print ("delegateCall is called!");
            // do some stuff
        }
    }

    @IBAction func buttonStopTapped (sender: AnyObject) {
        okToRun = false;
    }
}
```

Because this means that the background routine is still working.

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidate funtion. 
Like

```
var  thread = dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            self.someClass.beginService();
```

where do you want to stop

```
thread.invalidate()
```